# How to create dynamic Entity Framework query

Tags: entity-framework-6

how to create dynamic Entity Framework query. where we are getting dbset name from user as parameter and othere condition like column names and other where clause conditions

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Eval-Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

This library lets you evaluate, compile, and execute code at runtime. Almost all the C# language is supported.

You can find some example for LINQ Dynamic here: http://eval-expression.net/linq-dynamic

But you can do more like specifying the dbset and condition

Example

```
string set = "Entity1";
string whereClause = "x.ID > 2";

// CREATE the expression
string expression = "ctx." + set + ".Where(x => " + whereClause + ").ToList();";

// USING a context variable
var ctx = new EntityContext();
var list1 = Eval.Execute(expression, new {ctx});

// USING a context in the expression
EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterType(typeof(EntityContext));
var list2 = Eval.Execute("var ctx = new EntityContext();" + expression);
```